# Best practices to inject custom module in meanjs

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

As I understood there is no classical registration of module, where we can inject our dependencies like:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [otherModule]);
```

However there are file `module-name.client.module.js` at the root of the directorys

```
'use strict';
// Use Applicaion configuration module to register a new module
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('module-name');
```

Can I inject here my module like `*.registerModule('module-name', [someModule]);` or I should do it in `angular.module('articles').config(...)`?

But in `config` I can inject only `providers`, without `factories`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i used angular, the best practice to load custom module and external library
is to combine angularjs with requirejs.

It's done in 3 step.

First, load in your main html file a js file which builds the foundation of your system (require.config):
Here you have all the parameters allowed : https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Example :
In your html file :

```
<script src="path/to/require.js" data-main="path/to/yourBuildFile"></script>
```

In yourBuildFile file :

```
require.config({
    // you can define suitable names for all your external js library
    paths:{
        // don't put a ".js" at the end of the file
        'angular' : 'path/angular',
        'underscore' : 'path/underscore-min',
        '...': '...',
    },
    // and other useful things
});
```

Second, in the same file or in another (see the parameter deps in link above), bootstrap your app:
Like explained here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Example:

```
// AMD module injection, more info here : http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html
define([ // inject all the external library you need + the definition of your app
    'angular',
    'require',
    'yourpath/yourApp' // don't bother here, it's explained in third point
], function(angular){
    // link your app to the document file programatically
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['nameOfYourApp']); 
});
```

Third, you define your app (in the "yourpath/yourApp")

Example:

```
define([
    'angular',
    // put all path to your directives + controllers + services
], function(angular){ // only specify parameters the library you use in the function
    // you create your sublime app :)
    angular.module('nameOfYourApp', [
        // put all the name of your modules injected above
    ]);
});
```

The example above is made for single page application.
You can find other examples for multipage application here
http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html